# How to create histogram using D3.js and reading data from JSON

Tags: d3.js

I am using the below code. But I don't seem to find the error. My JSON file looks like the below link. I took this code from the D3.js website and just changes the data statement.

[image: My JSON Data]

Can anyone please guide me, where am I going wrong in this?
Would appreciate the help!!!

```js
var data = [
  ["Photofeed", 990],
  ["Geba", 962],
  ["Zoomcast", 955],
  ["Wikivu", 955],
  ["Oyoloo", 953],
  ["Vipe", 934],
  ["Rhynyx", 930],
];

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// X axis: scale and draw:
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 1000]) // can use this instead of 1000 to have the max of data: d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.price })
  .range([0, width]);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// set the parameters for the histogram
var histogram = d3.histogram()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.price;
  }) // I need to give the vector of value
  .domain(x.domain()) // then the domain of the graphic
  .thresholds(x.ticks(70)); // then the numbers of bins

// And apply this function to data to get the bins
var bins = histogram(data);

// Y axis: scale and draw:
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d) {
  return d.length;
})]); // d3.hist has to be called before the Y axis obviously
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// append the bar rectangles to the svg element
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(bins)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", 1)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")";
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0) - 1;
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.length);
  })
  .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is entirely different from theirs. You have an array of arrays, they have an array of objects.

They mention `d.price` somewhere in the code, replacing that by `d[1]` to get the second value from each array fixes it.

```js
var data = [
  ["Photofeed", 990],
  ["Geba", 962],
  ["Zoomcast", 955],
  ["Wikivu", 955],
  ["Oyoloo", 953],
  ["Vipe", 934],
  ["Rhynyx", 930],
];

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// X axis: scale and draw:
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 1000]) // can use this instead of 1000 to have the max of data: d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.price })
  .range([0, width]);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// set the parameters for the histogram
var histogram = d3.histogram()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d[1]; // <-- HERE it used to say d.price
  }) // I need to give the vector of value
  .domain(x.domain()) // then the domain of the graphic
  .thresholds(x.ticks(70)); // then the numbers of bins

// And apply this function to data to get the bins
var bins = histogram(data);

// Y axis: scale and draw:
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d) {
  return d.length;
})]); // d3.hist has to be called before the Y axis obviously
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// append the bar rectangles to the svg element
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(bins)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", 1)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")";
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0) - 1;
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.length);
  })
  .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```